# Prevent ArrayList.Add() from returning the index

Tags: .net, powershell, arraylist

is there a way to supress the return value (=Index) of an ArrayList
in Powershell (using System.Collections.ArrayList) or should I use
another class?

```
$myArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
$myArrayList.Add("test")
Output: 0
```

Comment: While all options presented here are valid, I personally go for [void] for one simple reason: The need for speed :)
Measure-Object is your friend. (There is a good blog article about speed for these things, but I can't find it at the moment, sorry)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can cast to void to ignore the return value from the Add method:

```
[void]$myArrayList.Add("test")
```

Another option is to redirect to $null:

```
$myArrayList.Add("test") > $null
```

Comment: I've discovered the problem with either of these is that it can't be outputted (e.g. `Write-Output`) when part of an existing sequence. E.g. I have an arraylist `$ADUsersList` that I add a record to via `.Add()`. When I then try to `Write-Output` `$ADUsersList` as part of the script, it's blank in my IDE. But as soon as the script is done running, and I just check `$ADUsersList` for contents, they get printed as I would expect.

Comment: I think you have some other issue going on.  Try this in PS >= 5 and you'll see it outputs the contents of the list: `$l = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new(); $l.Add("test") > $null; $l`

Comment: You're right; that does work. Not sure what about my situation is causing the difference (I'm inserting an ordered PSObject record into an ArrayList via `[void]$ArrayList.Add($objRecord)`. It worked if I checked `$ArrayList` after the script ran, but during the script any `Write-Output` attempts at displaying `$ArrayList`'s contents failed). Anyway, glad to see I was mistaken. It means debugging w/ ArrayLists is slightly easier than I thought.

Answer (score 28):

Two more options :)

Pipe to [out-null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null)

```
$myArrayList.Add("test") | Out-Null
```

Assign the result to $null:

```
$null = $myArrayList.Add("test")
```

Comment: Can you speak to the efficiency of piping to Out-Null versus > $null, or assigning to $null versus casting to [void]? Which of these four is most efficient?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell

Comment: why does arraylist add nulls in the list