# What is the ">" operator in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've tried searching around for this, and I can't find an answer, partially because it's difficult to search for the ">" character and also because the prompt in PowerShell uses that character.

I've got an example that works well, but I don't know what this line is doing exactly:

```
New-Item $tempCmd -Force -Type file > $null
```

I get the New-Item call and its parameters, but what is "> $null" doing exactly? And specifically what role does ">" play in this statement?

Comment: To pipe output to null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `>` character does output redirection.
In [an example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_Pipes_and_Redirection) it *seems* like it suppresses the output by redirecting it to null.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published a language specification for [PowerShell 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706) and [PowerShell 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36389).

From version 3.0:

> The redirection operator > takes the standard output from the pipeline and redirects it to the location designated by redirected-file-name, overwriting that location's current contents.

Your example has a null filename, so the output goes nowhere.

As [nochkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24333837/111424) says, people normally do this to stop a command from producing output. By default New-Item will output metadata about the new item to the host.

To acheive the same thing in a more readable way you can pipe the output to [`Out-Null`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849716.aspx).

```
New-Item $tempCmd -Force -Type file | Out-Null
```

From the documentation:

> Deletes output instead of sending it down the pipeline.