# Is there any way to hide messages when use mkdir with windows powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, mkdir

When use `mkdir` with powershell in windows, there is always messages after creating folders. How I can get rid of these messages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$null = mkdir folder`

Or

`[Void](mkdir folder)`

Or

`Mkdir folder | out-null`

Or

`Mkdir folder >$null`

Comment: I must user Void exactly as you said? That doesn't work for me.

Comment: Use `$null = yourcommand` instead of `[void]` ..is fastest way

Comment: You need to have brackets around the expression for `[void]` to work

Comment: Fixed cast to void syntax - it needed parens.