# What exactly does > $null do?

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

I know that this is a little dumb, but I've setup a custom profile that I end with a `Clear-Host` commandlet for Powershell and I hate that output from the previous commandlets flashes on the screen. I decided to send the output to null in an attempt to suppress the output, e.g.:

```
New-Alias -Name note -Value notpad.exe > $null
```

It seems to be working, but I'm not entirely certain as to what the command is doing. Is it okay to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`>` is a redirection operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx). This is common in the computing world, in unix (`> /dev/null`), and in Windows (`> NUL`). Often it's used to write to files or devices. In this case, you're sending it nowhere.

Other ways to do this in PowerShell:

```
Get-Something | Out-Null
[void](Get-Something)
$null = Get-Something
```

[Also here's a performance comparison between the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5260125/3905079).

Comment: The small sample set used in the answer you linked, obfuscates the fact that `$null` assignment and `void` casting is faster than redirection. Try [this one](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/IISResetMe/610deb873a96f331039d/raw/1175e21dcc410e4acbd41789c87ea7cf1e7ee666/Test-NullPerformance.ps1) with 1 million iterations or more

Answer (score 2):

Adding `> $null` to the end of a pipeline (or a single expression) throws away any result that would go to the default output.

It is one (of several) way to remove excess output (or return data if in a function).

In the case of `New-Alias` it would normally return a result representing the new alias, but sometimes that output gets in the way.