# Redirection to $null strange behavior in Powershell

Tags: powershell, null, powershell-2.0, void

There are four ways to suppress an output:

1. Redirection to `$null` variable

   ```bsh
   PS C:\> 1; $(2; return) > $null; 3
   1
   3
   ```
2. Piping to `Out-Null` cmdlet

   ```bsh
   PS C:\> 1; $(2; return) | Out-Null; 3
   1
   2
   ```
3. Casting to `[void]` type

   ```bsh
   PS C:\> 1; [void]$(2; return); 3
   1
   2
   ```
4. Assignment to `$null` variable

   ```bsh
   PS C:\> 1; $null = $(2; return); 3
   1
   2
   ```

All four cases are expected to be equivalent.

Why redirection to `$null` behaves different? Have I faced a bug?

#### An additional example

This example shows unexpected behavior of `> $null` command in PS 2.0:

```bsh
PS C:\> 1; $(Write-Output 2; Write-Host 3; return; Write-Host 4) > $null; 5
1
3
5
```

`return` command acts as if it exits from some nested context (though there is no command which creates it), stops `$()` expression execution and then continues the execution (when it shouldn't) in the current context to the `Write-Output 5` command.

### BEHAVIOR EXPLANATIONS

(from [*wOxxOm*'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42407253/7204581) answer)

- in PS 1.0 and 2.0 `> $null` operation is executed *before* `$()` expression and suppresses its output; `return` command does not exit from the current context (considered a **BUG**), but stops `$()` expression execution
- in PS 3.0 and newer `> $null` operation is executed *before* `$()` expression and suppresses its output in all cases; `return` command exits from the current context completely
- `| Out-Null`, `[void]`, `$null =` operations are executed *after* `$()` expression and suppress its output if there is no `return` command in it; `return` command exits from the current context completely

### SUMMARY

Different methods for suppressing command output:

1. `... > $null` redirection to `$null` variable
   *Bug in PS 1.0 and 2.0. In PS 3.0+ output may differ from other methods*
2. `... | Out-Null` piping to `Out-Null` cmdlet
   *Performance issues <sup>[*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263780/3959875)</sup>*
3. `[void]...` casting to `[void]` type
   *Advisable*
4. `$null = ...` assignment to `$null` variable
   *Advisable*

Comment: Regarding your edits: if you don't use `return` in expressions, which seems really weird, you can safely use `>$null` when it's more appropriate than casting or assigning.

Comment: @wOxxOm can I ask you for an example where `> $null` is more appropriate than casting or assigning?

Comment: I meant subjectively/semantically more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `2` is actually executed as `Write-Output 2`
- `$()` executes the enclosed code in the same context, it doesn't create a new context.

  Things that create a new context are scriptblocks like `& { ... }`, `1..2 | ForEach { ... }`,
  `({ ... }).Invoke()`, `select @{N='calculated property'; E={$_.foo}}` and functions.
- Thus, `$( return )` exits from the current context so **nothing should be evaluated after that** (in other words PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0 have a bug).

### Redirecting the output stream:

```
1; $(2; return) > $null; 3
```

The output stream itself of the entire `$()` expression is suppressed with `>$null`, which is decided before the expression is evaluated, `return` exits from the current context before `3` gets a chance.

PS 3 (and newer) correctly prints only `1`:

> 1

PS 1 and 2 incorrectly print both numbers and indeed it's a bug:

> 1
>   3

### Processing the output stream:

```
1; [void]$(2; return); 3
1; $null = $(2; return); 3
1; $(2; return) | Out-Null; 3
```

> 1
>   2

`2` is pushed to the output stream here, then `return` exits the current context before subsequent operation can take place (casting, assigning, pipelining).

As for performance differences, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263780/3959875): `| Out-Null` is the slowest because it *creates* a pipeline which is a complex process; the other methods discard the output, no extras created.

Comment: +1 but you might want to make it more clear why 3 is never executed. I dabbled quite some time on why PS 3.0 would only correctly print 1. It just shows my lack of knowledge but I can't be the only one ;)