# Hide powershell output

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$dest)

```
New-Item -force -path "$dest\1\" -itemtype directory
New-Item -force -path "$dest\2\" -itemtype directory
New-Item -force -path "$dest\3\" -itemtype directory

Copy-Item -path "C:\Development\1\bin\Debug\*" -destination "$dest\1\" -container -recurse -force
Copy-Item -path "C:\Development\2\bin\Debug\*" -destination "$dest\2\" -container -recurse -force
Copy-Item -path "C:\Development\3\bin\Debug\*" -destination "$dest\3\" -container -recurse -force
```

The script takes a string and copies all files and folders from the static origin path to the given root string, amending some folders for structure clarity.

It works fine but prints out the results from the "New-Item" commands and I would like to hide that. I've looked at the net and other questions on SE but no definitive answers to my problem were found.

In case someone is wondering - I am using "New-item" at the beginning in order to circumvent a flaw in PS' -recurse parameter not copying all subfolders correctly if the destination folder does not exist. (I.e. they are mandatory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the better (cleaner) way to ignore output in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell)

Comment: You repeat 3 times the same things.  I think your example code is a candidate for a for-loop.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Option 1: Pipe it to Out-Null

```
New-Item -Path c:\temp\foo -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
Test-Path c:\temp\foo
```

Option 2: assign to `$null` (faster than option 1)

```
$null = New-Item -Path c:\temp\foo -ItemType Directory
Test-Path c:\temp\foo
```

Option 3: cast to `[void]` (also faster than option 1)

```
[void](New-Item -Path c:\temp\foo -ItemType Directory)
Test-Path c:\temp\foo
```

See also: [What's the better (cleaner) way to ignore output in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell)