# Hide logs edge driver selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'd like to hide logs like that please :
[image: Logging]

Indeed, I want to developpe a console app and theses logs disturb the user experience :/

Thank you !

Comment: What do you mean? You want to hide logs which edgedriver prints to standard output?

Comment: Does this maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586382/hide-powershell-output

Comment: @AlexeyR. yes exactly, currently, my shell looks like this : https://ibb.co/v3SddL6 and I want to delete red part :)

Comment: anyone please ?