# extra azure account information showing in runbook results azure automation

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I want to know how to get rid of this extra account information that shows up every time i run a script in my azure automation runbook. There has to be a way to remove it, any help would be deeply appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append [Out-Null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null?view=powershell-7) to the commands that will output your account information. It hides the output instead of sending it down the pipeline or displaying it. See [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell) to ignore the output.

For example:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Out-Null
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```

Result

[image]