# PowerShell Copy-Item not creating subfolders

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I want Copy-Item to copy to the destination file and create any subfolders on the way, but I can't seem to get that to work.

```
Copy-Item $fullsrc $fulldst -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

`$fullsrc` and `$fulldst` are full paths with filenames as the destination filename is different from the source filename. Is there a way to get Copy-Item to create the subfolders and then copy the file over?

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: D:\mypath\logs\001.123.log
Destination: D:\newpath\newlogs\123.234.log".
Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'D:\newpath\newlogs\123.234.log'.
```

Comment: Create the destination folder in `$fulldst` first

Answer (score 1):

Copy-item have't function to create a folder, you need to previously create it

```
 Copy-Item $fullsrc $(new-item -ItemType Directory -Path $fulldst) -Recurse -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the parent directory of the destination file on your own.

```
# Split-Path with single parameter outputs the parent directory
$null = New-Item (Split-Path $fulldst) -ItemType Directory

Copy-Item $fullsrc $fulldst -Force -Verbose
```

Note that `-Recurse` switch has no use when you specify full source and destination file paths, so I've removed it.

Comment: I was pretty sure that `-Recurse` did nothing, but was just trying anything to see if it would work. I've not seen `$null = ` used in this way. Is this preferable to `| Out-Null`, or are they essentially identical constructs?

Comment: @YorSubs It is preferable to `Out-Null`, because it is much faster. See measurements here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263780/7571258