# How can you add values into an arraylist

Tags: powershell

I have 2 sets of variables

```
$numbers = "1","2","3"
$records = "A","B","C"
```

that I would like to join togther so the final output is

```
 Name                           Value                                  
 ----                           -----                                                                                                                                      
 A                              {1}                                     
 B                              {2}                                     
 C                              {3}
```

so far I have managed to build the Arraylist

```
$numbers = "1","2","3"
$records = "A","B","C"

$total = [ordered] @{}
Foreach ($entry in $records){ $total[$entry] = New-Object Collections.Arraylist }
```

Which gives me

```
 Name                           Value                                  
 ----                           -----                                                                                                                                      
 A                              {}                                     
 B                              {}                                     
 C                              {}
```

However when I try add the numbers in I get this result and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please can someone nudge me in the right direction. Thank you.

```
ForEach ($row in $numbers)

    { $total[$records] += $row}

  Name                           Value                                  
 ----                           -----                                                                                                                                      
 A                              {}                                     
 B                              {}                                     
 C                              {}
 {A, B, C}                      {, , , 3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice start. Your current approach just needs to account for when you encounter a new key or an existing key.

The main approach you could take is iterate the records, and first check if the record exists as a key in the hash table. If it does, create a new [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1), otherwise add the number to the existing key's `ArrayList`. This assumes that both arrays are equal length.

Here is one way of doing that:

```
$numbers = "1","2","3"
$records = "A","B","C"

$total = [ordered] @{}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $records.Length; $i++) {
    $record = $records[$i]

    # Check if record key exists here
    if ($total.Keys -notcontains $record) {

        # Create new array list for the new record key found
        $total[$record] = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Arraylist
    }

    # Add item to array list in hashtable
    [void]$total[$record].Add($numbers[$i])
}

$total
```

For checking if the keys exists, I used [`-notcontains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#-notcontains) to check if the key exists in the hashtable `Keys`. You can have a look at [`about_comparison_operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7) for more information on the available operators available in PowerShell.

Additionally, to add an object to an `ArrayList`, you can use [`System.Collections.ArrayList.Add(Object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.add?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_ArrayList_Add_System_Object_). This method returns the type `int`, which is the index of the value added. This means that you will get the indices outputted to the screen every time an object is added. To suppress this, I casted `void`, which ignores the return value. If you want to know other ways of doing this, have a look at this [Prevent ArrayList.Add() from returning the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149159/prevent-arraylist-add-from-returning-the-index) question.

**Output:**

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
A                              {1}
B                              {2}
C                              {3}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and it helped a great deal with my understanding.

Comment: @Jamie_lee No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If the braces are un-important, since the value you are displaying is just a hash:

```
$numbers = "1","2","3"
$records = "A","B","C"
$hash    = [ordered]@{}

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $numbers.Length; $i++ ) {
    for( $j = 0; $j -lt $records.Length; $j++ ) {
        if( $i -eq $j ) {
            $hash[ "$( $records[ $j ])" ] = "$( $numbers[ $i ] )"
            continue
        }
    }
}

$hash
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
A                              1
B                              2
C                              3
```