# Correctly return array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell an tried a function which generates an array.

```
function array_create {
    $array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $array.Add('hello')
    $array.Add('world')
    return $array
}

$arr = array_create
foreach($a in $arr){
   $a
}
```

even if I put @() arround the function call the output is

```
0
1
hello
world
```

how would I correctly return an array with only values (no numbers) and why does this happen ?

Comment: `[void]$array.Add('hello')` or `$null = $array.Add('hello')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent ArrayList.Add() from returning the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149159/prevent-arraylist-add-from-returning-the-index)

Comment: Thanks RoadRunner that actually did answer the question. Sorry Didn't find it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the [*Add* method of *ArrayList* Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.add?view=netcore-3.1) returns an `[int]` value:

```
$array = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$array.Add
```

> ```
> OverloadDefinitions
> -------------------
> int Add(System.Object value)
> int IList.Add(System.Object value)
> ```

Use `[void]$array.Add('hello')` or `$null = $array.Add('hello')`.

The `$array.Add('hello') | Out-Null` is possible but not recommended in loops for its negative performance impact.

Comment: Thanks JosefZ for the hint and the explenation