# Compare values in array and return list of results (Powershell)

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I am working in Azure and trying to loop through all Subscriptions tags in my tenant and return all results in a list with a specific tag name + value. The idea is to auto alert certain people when platform changes are happening or incidents occur (sort of cheap mans ITSM).

```
$SubTags.Properties.TagsProperty

$ArrayOfTags = @()

ForEach($s in $SubTags) {
if ($SubTags.Properties.TagsProperty -contains "Environment"){
    $ArrayOfTags += $SubTags
}
else { 
        Write-Host "fail"
     }
}
Return $ArrayOfTags
```

All i get is:

```
fail
fail
fail
fail
fail
fail
fail
....
```

I have tried with some dummy code

```
$aa = @("aa","bb","cc", "cc")
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$bbb = @()

ForEach ($a in $aa){
if ($aa -eq "cc") {
$bbb.Add($_)  
    Write-Host "cool cool cool"
}
else {
    Write-Host ":("
}
}

Return $bbb
```

And i get:

```
0
cool cool cool
1
cool cool cool
2
cool cool cool
3
cool cool cool
```

Returned.

I appreciate that this might be a bit to vague, but I am new to ps, so appreciate any sort of help :-)

Good day

Comment: You should be using $s in your loop… not $subtags

Comment: I am pretty sure the object that stores the tag is a dictionary and it is per resource in the subscription, so if you have multiple dictionaries, you need to use your loop and test the individual dictionary (as Doug has said above, use `$s` in your loop) using the `$s.ContainsKey("name you wish to find")` method. If it exists, you can use the index property to get the value `$s["name you wish to find"]`. You may want to return [custom objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1) with the resource name too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell ArrayList magically inserts a zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641400/powershell-arraylist-magically-inserts-a-zero) or [A: Prevent ArrayList.Add() from returning the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149205/1701026)

Comment: AS was said above you are referring to the wrong variable name in the loop - it should be $s

Comment: `foreach($thing in $collectionOfThings) { <# do something with $thing, not the whole collection #> }`

Comment: Ah of course - thank you all so much!! Highly appreciated.